# Low-Level Mouse Hook - WM_MOUSEWHEEL event data

Tags: c#, hook, mouse

I've implemented low level mouse hook as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/toub/low-level-mouse-hook-in-c

It works fine. The only question is for WM_MOUSEWHEEL event - how to detect wheel rotation direction (forward or backward).
The system provides additional data in `mouseData` field only. In my tests `mouseData` = 7864320 for forward rotation and `mouseData`=4287102976 for backward rotation always.

So question: how to parse `mouseData` to detect the wheel rotation direction and possibly additional data related to the event?

`mouseData` comes from `lParam`

The hook provides `lParam` which is parsed as:

```
public struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
{
    public POINT pt;
    public uint mouseData;
    public uint flags;
    public uint time; 
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}
```

Comment: I recommend reading the docs. Start with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) which links to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)) and perhaps use the [`WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousewheel?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thanks. I've missed the documentation somewhy. It's clear now.